# Grails scaffolding template (install-templates) customization documentation

Tags: grails, customization, scaffolding

Every time I need to customize my templates for scaffolding in Grails I do it by example, looking the code inside the artifacts generated by the command install-templates. But I've never found a documentation for that. I don't know what kind of objects or tags I can use.
For example, in the artifact/Controller.groovy has "`@artifact.name@`", "`@artifact.package@`"; In the scaffolding/Controller.groovy has "`${className}`", "`${propertyName}`", and even gsp tags like "`<%=packageName ? "package ${packageName}\n\n" : ''%>`".

How can I know the structure or what others objects or tags I can use? I wonder where it's documented.